# counting the values in multiple columns at once

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe,df as below

```
Index        DateTimestamp                a        b        c     
 0        2017-08-03 00:00:00            ta        bc      tt       
 1        2017-08-03 00:00:00            re                        
 3        2017-08-03 00:00:00                      cv      ma 

 4        2017-08-04 00:00:00                                     
 5        2017-09-04 00:00:00                      cv             
 :                 :                      :         :       :      
 :                 :                      :         :       :
```

I want to group by 1day the count of values in each column by not considering the empty values in each column. So the output will be

```
 Index                        a        b        c 
2017-08-03 00:00:00           2        2        2
2017-08-04 00:00:00           0        1        0
```

I have tried this but not want i want:

```
df2=df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='DeviceDateTimeStamp', freq='1D')]) ['a','b','c'].apply(pd.Series.count)
```

Comment: `df2=df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='DeviceDateTimeStamp', freq='1D')]) ['a','b','c'].count()` ?

Comment: I tried this code but it counts the occurrences of the dates day by day and not the values of the columns.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) or [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) for remove times with [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) for exclude count missing values:

```
print (df)
   Index        DateTimestamp    a    b    c
0      0  2017-08-03 00:00:00   ta   bc   tt
1      1  2017-08-03 00:00:00   re  NaN  NaN
2      3  2017-08-03 00:00:00  NaN   cv   ma
3      4  2017-08-04 00:00:00  NaN  NaN  NaN
4      5  2017-09-04 00:00:00  NaN   cv  NaN

df2=df.groupby(df['DateTimestamp'].dt.floor('d'))['a','b','c'].count()
#another solution
#df2=df.groupby(df['DateTimestamp'].dt.date)['a','b','c'].count()
print (df2)
               a  b  c
DateTimestamp         
2017-08-03     2  2  2
2017-08-04     0  0  0
2017-09-04     0  1  0
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
   Index        DateTimestamp   a   b   c
0      0  2017-08-03 00:00:00  ta  bc  tt
1      1  2017-08-03 00:00:00  re        
2      3  2017-08-03 00:00:00      cv  ma
3      4  2017-08-04 00:00:00            
4      5  2017-09-04 00:00:00      cv
```

Or if possible numeric values in `a,b,c` columns:

```
c = ['a','b','c']
df2=df[c].astype(str).ne('').groupby(df['DateTimestamp'].dt.floor('d')).sum().astype(int)
print (df2)
               a  b  c
DateTimestamp         
2017-08-03     2  2  2
2017-08-04     0  0  0
2017-09-04     0  1  0
```

Comment: It didnt work. It still gives the same values to all the columns for each day

Comment: OK, solution working if missing values are `NAN`s, what are your missing values? Emtry strings? Spaces?

Comment: The missing values are empty cell spaces

Comment: @Bode - How working `df.ne('').groupby(df['DateTimestamp'].dt.floor('d'))['a','b','c'].sum()` ?

Comment: @Bode - If check `df.ne('')` it return True for missing cells?

Comment: @Bode - what about `df.astype(str).ne('')`  ?

Comment: thanks!! It is working now. Can you update the answer so i can mark the tick

Comment: @Bode - Please check edit - better solution like astype ;)

Comment: why is the astype(int) needed?

Comment: @Bode - because you count `True` values by `sum` and output are floats ;) So for integers need converting.

Comment: @Bode - For me seaborn and matplotlib is hard, so no idea about solution, sorry :(